# Google Analytics SDK 3 iOS - Example from Google not working?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm trying to copy/past the [example from Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/advanced):

```
 id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// Set screen name on the tracker to be sent with all hits.
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
       value:@"Home Screen"];

// Send a screen view for "Home Screen".
[tracker send:[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView]];

// This event will also be sent with &cd=Home%20Screen.
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"UX"
                                                      action:@"touch"
                                                       label:@"menuButton"
                                                       value:nil] build]];

// Clear the screen name field when we're done.
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
       value:nil];
```

And Xcode is telling me:
Incompatible pointer type sending 'GAIDictionaryBuilder *' to parameter of type 'NSDictionnary *' on the second line (`[tracker send:[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView]];`)

When I run the app, it crashes with this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GAIDictionaryBuilder objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16060d70'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. did you import the necessary GA SDK into project (via Cocoapods or manually)
2. did you import the GAI headers in this particular class?
3. it looks like your screen view tracking code is incomplete.
4. you event tracking code looks legit.
5. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me today and it turned out to be an issue where I overlooked the build part of that line.

You have 2 GAIDictionary lines there and only one is using build. Try changing it to:

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

This worked for me.